# NumberFormatException with File IO

Tags: java, file-io, numberformatexception

I keep getting a NumberFormatException, which I understand arises due to a string conversion.  I am converting st.nexttoken to a double with Double.parseDouble.
Any help would be much appreciated!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FileIO {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        double sum = 0, next ;
        int ctr = 0;
        String line;  
        String filename = "numbers.txt";
        StringTokenizer st;
        PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("output.txt");
        outFile.println("Output File");
        try{
            Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader (filename));
            while (inFile.hasNext())
            {
                line = inFile.nextLine();
                st = new StringTokenizer(line);
                while (st.hasMoreTokens()){
                    next = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
                    sum += next;
                    ctr++;
                    System.out.println(next);
                    outFile.println(next);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("number of doubles read is " + ctr);
            System.out.println("average is " + sum/(double)ctr);
            outFile.println("number of doubles read is " + ctr);
            outFile.println("average is " + sum/(double)ctr);
            outFile.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("The file numbers.txt was not found");
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println("sorry - number format error");
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The error from NetBeans reads sorry - number format error
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Output"

numbers.txt has some integers as well as doubles with decimal points.

output.txt is blank, but saved in the same file path as numbers.txt

Here is the body of numbers.txt as requested.
13 12 15 3

74.4 67.3 43.8 77.7 233.4 678.9

Comment: Try printing our the token before converting it to find out whether the token is actually a number

Comment: Could you post numbers.txt in the question? You might have a word "Output" inside. BTW you never close input file.

Comment: post the contents of numbers.txt, otherwise all people can do is offer debugging suggestions.

Comment: I added numbers.txt to the bottom. I checked it, and there isn't the word Output inside.

Comment: Here is a e.printStackTrace()                                  java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Output"
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
 at FileIO.main(FileIO.java:27)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    double sum = 0, next ;
    int ctr = 0;
    String line;
    String filename = "numbers.txt";
    StringTokenizer st;
    PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("output.txt");
    outFile.println("Output File");
    try{
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(filename));
        while (inFile.hasNext())
        {
            line = inFile.nextLine();
            st = new StringTokenizer(line);
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()){
                next = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
                sum += next;
                ctr++;
                System.out.println(next);
                outFile.println(next);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("number of doubles read is " + ctr);
        System.out.println("average is " + sum/(double)ctr);
        outFile.println("number of doubles read is " + ctr);
        outFile.println("average is " + sum/(double)ctr);
        outFile.flush();
        inFile.close();
        outFile.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("The file numbers.txt was not found");
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.println("sorry - number format error");
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Above is modified version of your code and it works fine with the below given number.txt.

You need use the flush() write it to the final destination.

Here is the number.txt

```
12 12.0 12
12 32 56
34
34.0
```

Comment: Still you are getting NumberFormatException?

Comment: Still you are getting NumberFormatException? If you are getting the same error as you mentioned then your file may contain some string in it. Check whether you are refering the same file you have mentioned. I have did lot of times by refering wrong file. to avoid the confusion use full path and test. Just to make sure.